# mule anypointstudio failed to read schema

Tags: mule, mule-el

I worked in

> Anypoint Studio January 2015 Release
>
> Version: 5.0.0

I added below jars

1. mule-module-s3-2.0
2. mule-module-devkit-support-3.4.0

again I got exception like below

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mule.api.Capabilities
```

Answer (score 0):

I heard that January 2015 release has few issues.

Try this release evrsion:

Anypoint Studio March 2015 Release
Version: 5.1.0
Build Id: 201503171252

Comment: if you can find a link to above release and its notes that will be help to community. thanks